# Sort function with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I have an array of object like below:

```
var data = [
  {
    name": "Name2",
    "webOrderingEnabled": true,
    "distance": 1.6989125091571928
  },
  {
    "name": "Name3",
    "webOrderingEnabled": false,
    "distance": 1.9178283920396098
  },
  {
    "name": "Name4",
    "webOrderingEnabled": false,
    "shutdown": {
      "message": "",
      "status": true
    },
    "distance": 6.94478210395609
  },
  {
    "name": "Name1",
    "webOrderingEnabled": true,
    "shutdown": {
      "message": "",
      "status": false
    },
    "distance": 0.5368834377514055
  }
]
```

I want to sort this array of object
1.webOrderingEnabled
2.shutdown.status = false
3. Distance
The challenge  is some object don't  have shutdown key if it's not present consider to be store open
i tried below approach it did't worked for me

```
  data.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a.shutdown?.status && b.shutdown?.starus || !a.shutdown?.status && !b.shutdown?.status && 
       a.webOrderingEnabled || b.webOrderingEnabled) {
              return a.distance - b.distance;
            }
            if (a.shutdown?.status) {
              return -1;
            }
            return 1;
          });
```

Expected:

```
 [{
  "name": "Name1",
  "webOrderingEnabled": true,
  "shutdown": {
  "message": "",
  "status": false
  },
  "distance": 0.5368834377514055
  },
  {
  "name": "Name2",
  "webOrderingEnabled": true
  "distance": 1.6989125091571928
  },
  {
  "name": "Name3",
  "webOrderingEnabled": false,
  "distance": 1.9178283920396098
  },
  {
  "name": "Name4",
  "webOrderingEnabled": false,
  "shutdown": {
  "message": "",
  "status": true
  },
  "distance": 6.94478210395609
  }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if you want to sort an array of objects according to fields A, B, C (in this order) you simply do:

```
if (a.A < b.A) return -1;
else if (a.A > b.A) return 1;
// otherwise a.A == b.A, so let's proceed with considering B now...

if (a.B < b.B) return -1;
else if (a.B > b.B) return 1;
// otherwise a.A == b.A && a.B == b.B, so let's proceed with considering C now...
if (a.C < b.C) return -1;
else if (a.C > b.C) return 1;
return 0;
```

Here you can think of `a.A < b.A` as pseudocode for comparing that single attribute value, exactly how that is done depends on the types.

So your code should look something like

```
// I assume by "consider to be store open" you mean shutdown.status === false
function getShutdownStatus(a) {
    return a?.shutdown?.status || false;
}
data.sort((a, b) => {
  // Use ! here because true > false but it seems you want true to come first
  if (!a.webOrderingEnabled < !b.webOrderingEnabled) return -1;
  else if (!a.webOrderingEnabled > !b.webOrderingEnabled) return 1;
  const aShutdown = getShutdownStatus(a);
  const bShutdown = getShutdownStatus(b);
  if (aShutdown < bShutdown) return -1;
  else if (aShutdown > bShutdown) return 1;
  // otherwise compare by distance
  if (a.distance < b.distance) return -1;
  else if (a.distance > b.distance) return 1
  return 0;
});
```

Once you have this working you can simplify the code:

```
data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.webOrderingEnabled != b.webOrderingEnabled) return b.webOrderingEnabled - a.webOrderingEnabled;
  const aShutdown = getShutdownStatus(a);
  const bShutdown = getShutdownStatus(b);
  if (aShutdown != bShutdown) return aShutdown - bShutdown;
  return a.distance - b.distance;
});
```